# Changing connectionstring area of app.config in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I need to change the connectionstring area of my aap.config file in vb.net.  I have tried several codes but nothing worked for me.  I was suggested following code

```
 Dim config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
    Dim connectionStringsSection = DirectCast(config.GetSection("connectionStrings"), ConnectionStringsSection)
    connectionStringsSection.ConnectionStrings("Blah").ConnectionString = "Data Source=blah;Initial Catalog=blah;UID=blah;password=blah"
    config.Save()
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings")
```

But I do not understand what will be "Blah" in my code?  Also how does this change the text?

Secondly, if I use Readalltext and replacetext and then writealltext, will it be ok or it can cause any problems?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store and retrieve connection string from app.config use the following method:

Create a key in app.config:

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="ConnectionString" value=""/>
 </appSettings>
```

To set value of connection string:

```
 Dim config As System.Configuration.Configuration
    Dim fileMap As New ExeConfigurationFileMap()

    fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = "Path of app.config"
    config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None)

    '   Sets values to config file.
    If config.HasFile() Then

        config.AppSettings.Settings.Item("ConnectionString").Value = "Data Source=blah;Initial Catalog=blah;UID=blah;password=blah"
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified)
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("AppSettings")

    End If
```

To get the value of Connection String:

```
  Dim config As System.Configuration.Configuration
    Dim fileMap As New ExeConfigurationFileMap()

 fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = "Path of app.config"
    config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None)

    '   Sets values to config file.
    If config.HasFile() Then

        strConnString = config.AppSettings.Settings.Item("ConnectionString").Value

    End If
```

Here strConnString  is a string variable which will store connection string value.

Comment: I am using VS2013, VB.NET 4.0. This code doesn't work as is for my project - how do I need to adjust this to work with my project?